# Proof using Mantel's Theorem on a simple 2-connected graph G with (G) ≥ 3.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

**Let $G$ be a simple $n$-vertex triangle free graph with $\delta(G) \geq 3$. Prove that if $n \leq 11$, then $G$ is $3$-edge-connected. Show that such a graph could be not $2$-(vertex)-connected.**

Hint: Using Mantel's Theorem can help.

Mantel's Theorem: Let $f(n)$ be the maximum number of edges in a simple $n$-vertex graph with no triangles. For each $n\geq 1$, $f(n)=\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$.

I started by proving by contrapositive. Here is the following claim: If $G$ is not $3$-edge-connected, then $n>11$.

I do not know what my next steps should be from here. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction from here?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Mathjax to format mathematics. Suppose your graph is triangle-free and has a 2-edge cut. This decomposes your graph into two smaller parts. Can you reach a contradiction from this?